# Font Awesome does not work with Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, font-awesome

I am using laravel 4 and Font-Awesome but when I put my library like is natural in: public/fonts/ it doesn't work, I actualy tryed with public/css/ but it doesn't works too I just get weird symbols. Can everyone please help me with this.

Comment: looks like you are not linking correctly the assets in <head> section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works perfectly fine for me when including fontawesome in the head like this

```
    {{ HTML::style('fonts/font-awesome.min.css') }}
```

You don't need to use public in the directories, as laravel assumes this to be the path and adds it automatically by default.

Comment: are you sure that you have the correct fontawesome files in the directory? I would recommend installing stuff like this with bower for example, that will make your live much easier!

Answer (score 0):

You could put: `<link href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

[image]